# Any VI like editor under windows?

Tags: windows, vim, windows-7, vi

I am wondering whether there is a vi like editor under windows command line?

Comment: Would running vi under cygwin be an acceptable answer? Alternatively there is a cmd.exe version of vi, but I have not used it personally: http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc

Comment: What's wrong with vim for windows straight from vim.org?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a [search engine or link farm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/172661) or a [product recommendation site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172661). This question, while it's about a programmer's editor, is not an appropriate question for SO.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? It's not fair..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just download vim for windows from http://www.vim.org -- on the installation it will ask if you want to create shortcuts for calling it from the command line. Then you can just `vim <filename>`.

Comment: Is GVIM different than the VIM you suggested?

Answer (score 2):

[Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) has vi mode, eclipse has few vi plugins, using cygwin, or as Juan said go with gvim

Comment: I use Vrapper with eclipse which is nice. [http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/)